# ATC Broadcast - Similar to Channel 9

Tags: air-travel, in-flight-services

Does anyone know if KLM Airlines has a feature in the IFE screen that allows you to listen to radio communication, similar to what United has with Channel 9?

Comment: Just curious, what radio communications are available in channel 9?

Comment: @NeanDerThal, It is live audio from the aircraft's ATC radio. It was on channel 9 when the aircraft entertainment system was a dozen or so numbered audio channels, it is now called something like "From the Cockpit" in the audio channels or from the Route Map in a modern entertainment system. I've only ever seen this on United airplanes.

Comment: I too have only ever seen this on United